# Print a receipt for an order?

Tags: java

I'm making a program that allows a user to order some food from a cafe and then prints the receipt for the food. I want to print on a receipt the product ordered and only the product ordered, along with the quantity and the price * quantity. I found that using an array is the only way I can get the items ordered in a list format. The problem is it shows the items not ordered as a null value with $0. I want it to display only the items ordered. Also, I can't figure out how to display the quantity of each item next to the item ordered.

**Product class**

```
import java.util.Scanner; //program uses class Scanner

    public void displayMenu() {
        System.out.printf("%-12s%12s%12s%n", "======", getBelliFreschiName(), "======");
        System.out.printf("%-12s%12s%14s%n", "1    ", getStarbucksName(), "    $" + getStarbucksPrice());
        System.out.printf("%-8s%12s%22s%n", "2    ", getTazoName(), "    $" + getTazoPrice());
        System.out.printf("%-12s%12s%16s%n", "3    ", getEinsteinName(), "    $" + getEinsteinPrice());
        System.out.printf("%-12s%12s%15s%n", "4    ", getKrusteazName(), "    $" + getKrusteazPrice());
        System.out.printf("%-12s%12s%12s%n", "======", "==================", "======");
    }

    public void orderProduct() {
        do {
            System.out.println("Please Enter A Product Number Between 1-4 or Press 0 to Exit");
            product = input.nextInt();

            if (product == 0) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Please Enter Quantity");
            quantity = input.nextInt();

            switch (product) {
                case 1:
                    coffeePrice = 2.11;
                    subTotal += (2.11 * quantity);
                    selectedValue[1] = 2.11 * quantity;
                    nameProduct[1] = "Starbucks Coffee";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    teaPrice = 2.51;
                    subTotal += (2.51 * quantity);
                    selectedValue[2] = 2.51 * quantity;
                    nameProduct[2] = "Tazo Tea";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    bagelPrice = 3.14;
                    subTotal += (3.14 * quantity);
                    selectedValue[3] = 3.14 * quantity;
                    nameProduct[3] = "Einstein Bagel";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    muffinPrice = 3.54;
                    subTotal += (3.54 * quantity);
                    selectedValue[4] = 3.54 * quantity;
                    nameProduct[4] = "Krusteaz Muffin";
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid product No.");
            }
        }
        while (product != 0);
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(nameProduct[i] + " " + " $" + selectedValue[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f", "\nSubtotal: $", subTotal);
        System.out.printf("%5s%.2f", "\nTax: $", (subTotal * tax));
        System.out.printf("%4s%.2f", "\nTotal: $", (subTotal + (subTotal * tax)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: it seems that you are starting to learn to program. I wholeheartedly recommend to also start learning **good** programming style. Meaning - spend some time reading a book like "Clean code" from Martin Fowler.

Comment: Don't post your entire code since it contains parts which is not related to your problem. Instead spend some time on creating [minimal example reproducing your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (also known as [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: A product is not a menu. So the product class should represent just one product. It can have a name and a price. It shouldn't have a separate name and separate price for every possible product because then the restaurant will need to recompile the program every time they add to the menu. So the menu should be something different. And then perhaps you'll be able to re-think the array.

Comment: Yea I'm just starting to code. Thanks for the info. Will definitely check out "Clean Code". My bad on posting the whole code. This was my first Stack Overflow post. Right. That makes sense on having a product class for each product.

Comment: Agree with @Jägermeister: clean code is a great book, and it gets even better after a few shots of Jägermeister... :)

Comment: lol I have been sipping Hennessy during late night coding sessions. Will try  Jager and Clean Code for sure.

Answer (score 0):

How about the second question first.

> Also, I can't figure out how to display the quantity of each item next to the item ordered.

One way to do this without making extensive changes to your program is to create another array. You could declare it right next to the others, like so:

```
double[] selectedValue = new double[5];
String[] nameProduct = new String[5];
int[] quantityOrdered = new int[5];
```

In the do-while loop where you record the selected value, you could change that code like so:

```
case 1:
    coffeePrice = 2.11;
    subTotal += (2.11 * quantity);
    selectedValue[1] = 2.11 * quantity;
    quantityOrdered[1] = quantity;
    nameProduct[1] = "Starbucks Coffee";
```

And where you print things out, you could write:

```
System.out.println( "Product: " + nameProduct[i]
    + " Quantity: " + quantityOrdered[i]
    + " $"+selectedValue[i]);
```

There, problem solved.

And that makes the first problem trivial. Just check for `quantityOrdered[i] != 0` before printing.

```
if (quantityOrdered[i] != 0)
    System.out.println( "Product: " + nameProduct[i]
        + " Quantity: " + quantityOrdered[i]
        + " $"+selectedValue[i]);
```

Generally speaking, it would be better to make this more object oriented and rely less on literal values, but this at least will get you farther down the road.

Comment: I was just about to do that! It was on the tip of my tongue but I couldn't exactly figure it out. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have something against using index[0] in arrays, you should work on your emotions and get over it - otherwise it will get you into "off-by-one" bugs in the future!

Further, the reason for the "nulls" is that you print *all* the entries in the product arrays, regardless if the user chose them or not, in order to avoid printing the nulls you can wrap the printing with a check:

```
if (nameProduct[i] != null) {
    System.out.println(nameProduct[i] + " " + " $" + selectedValue[i]);
}
```

If you'd like to print *all* the products, including those that weren't purchased, you should initialize `nameProduct` to hold all the names beforehand, and `selectedValue` should also be initialized to zeros.

As for displaying the quantity, right now you're using the same parameter and overriding it with any iteration inside the `while` loop, if you want to persist it as well, you can create `productQuantity` array and save the quantity into it for each product, same as you do for `selectedValue`.

---

All that said... A better Object-oriented approach would be to have a "cart" object, which will have a "List of products" and "total". Product should be an object as well, with the fields: name, price, quantity and total. You can have a `toString()` method which will print these fields respectfully. Something like the following:

```
class Cart {
    double total = 0;
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    void addProductToCart(Product p) {
        products.add(p);
        total += p.total;
    }

    void displayCart() {
        for (Product p: products)
            System.out.println(p);

        System.out.println("Total cart value: " + total);
    }
}

class Product {
    String name;
    double price;
    int quantity;
    double total;

    Product(String name, double price, int quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.total = price * quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "  $" + price + "  Q: " + quantity + "   $" + total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha my emotions. I only started the array at 1 because it was printing the zero one as a null. Thank you so much for your input. I will apply this to the code.

Comment: @CodeMajic please check out the addition I've added to the answer!

Comment: That's awesome. I'm supposed to be using object an object oriented approach anyway. This definitely makes more sense. Thanks.